# Formula to get cell values of specific column and a variable row number

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need a formula to retrieve a value defined by a specific column (always B) and a variable row number (A).

What is the formula I need to write in column C to retrieve the right names as shown below?

```
 _A_____B_______C_____
  3 | Lucas |  Gary      <--B3
 _____________________
  1 | Mark  |  Lucas     <--B1
 _____________________
  2 | Gary  |  Mark      <--B2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/INDIRECT-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) function.

Column C should be:

```
=INDIRECT("B" & $A1)
=INDIRECT("B" & $A2)
=INDIRECT("B" & $A3)
```

(you can just enter the formula in the first cell and copy it down)